# Given a group $G$, how can I prove that $K = \{x^2 : x \in G\}$ is a subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $G$ be an abelian group with identity $e$. Consider the sets $H = \{x \in G : x^2 = e\}$ and
>   $K = \{x^2 : x \in G\}$. Then prove that both $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$.

I need to prove that $K$ is a subgroup of $G$. Can someone help me with that part? I do NOT need the proof for the subgroup $H$, just the subgroup $K$.

I know I have to prove closure, the identity, and the inverse, but I would appreciate if someone could write it out for me so I understand it. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please have a look at our [basic MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to typeset math here.

Comment: The elements of the proof for $K$ are similar to those for $H$.  Where are you having trouble making the correspondence?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I understood the identity because as Travis put, e^2 is equal to e, so the identity is in the group G. I am however struggling with proving the inverse and the closure. I do not know how to prove that for all x belonging to H, then (x^2)^-1 also belongs to H. Sorry for asking for help, I know this is elementary abstract algebra stuff.

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate...just don't know where it is.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You need to show the identity is in $K$... not hard, $e^2=e$.

If $x\in K$ is $x^{-1}\in K$?  (Also not too hard.)

Is the set closed?  I.e. if $x, y$ are in $K$ is $xy$ in $K$?  This is the time that $G$ being abelian will be important.

The other properties like associativity follow from the operation on $G$.

Comment: For the inverse, do I have to prove that (x^2)^-1 belongs to K or just x^-1 belongs to K? Sorry for asking

Comment: Let $z \in K$. That is, there exists an $x \in G$ so that $x^2=z$. You need to show $z^{-1}=(x^2)^{-1} \in K$.

Comment: You need to show that $(x^2)^{-1}$ is in $K$... check to see if $(x^{-1})^2=(x^{2})^{-1}$.  Remember that $G$ is abelian (that will make the answer yes).  I'll leave it to you to see exactly why.

Comment: I know I have to go about proving that but is it many steps to go through. Would I just show that (x^-1)(x^-1) = (x^-1 x^-1) in the end... I'm just not sure if my proof will be right

Comment: I was also thinking of letting a = x^2 and b = y^2 and showing that for all a, b belonging to K, there exists ab^-1 belonging to K but I am unsure if that would be correct

Comment: That would work.  What would $(ab)^{-1}$ be?  Is it a square?  If so, it is in $K$ and you are done.

Comment: It was a square, so thank you very much for helping. Last question, I promise. If I am showing it is closed, I know I have to let x^2 and y^2 be part of H. But what am I trying to prove? Am I trying to prove x^2 y^2 = (xy)^2?

Comment: $a=x^2$ is in $K$ and $b=y^2$ is in $K$.  Is $ab=(x^2)(y^2)$ in $K$?  Here you use the fact that $G$ is abelian.  $ab=(x^2)(y^2)=xxyy=(xy)(xy)=(xy)^2$... so the product $ab$ is in $K$.  Note that $xxyy\neq xyxy$ for groups that are not abelian.